# How to differentiate between the string "null" and the null value when converting xml to json?

Tags: java, json, xml

In my app, a person with the last name of "Null" was entered, but whenever I try to pull the record up, the last name field is always blank.

The name is being stored correctly in the database, but it's when the xml results that retrieve the record are parsed into JSON that `<LastName>null</LastName>` becomes `"LastName": null` instead of `"LastName": "null"`

I use org.json.XML.toJSONObject to convert from xml to json.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I've just tried it and can confirm: `XML.toJSONObject("<foo>null</foo>");` will produce an attribute `foo` with value `null`, which is an incredibly stupid default, IMO. I'm afraid the only way to turn this of with this feature is to keep all values as strings `XML.toJSONObject("<foo>null</foo>", true);`. This turns of JSON trying to guess which values are which datatypes (i.e. numbers will also be strings), but it also turns off this stupid default.

Comment: It sounds like a bug in the framework TBH

Comment: Reminds me of little bobby tables :-)

Comment: @DavidBrossard Nullity Nancy?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Could you add your response as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Another solution would be to post-process the generated JSON (which many applications will probably need to do anyway).

Comment: Undesrcore-java library can convert xml to json. <LastName>null</LastName> will be converted to the {
  "LastName": "null",
  "#omit-xml-declaration": "yes"
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with Joachim's answer:

```
XML.toJSONObject(xml, true);
```

This keeps all values as strings and will convert `<LastName>null</LastName>` to `"LastName": "null"`